# Download image and replace it in Resources

Tags: codenameone

I have .jpg image, that is used in theme, thanks to this piece of code I can change the theme

```
Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
h.put("bgImage", fetchResourceFile().getImage("black.png"));
UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(h);
f.refreshTheme();
```

And I would like to download image from URL the image with the same name (blank.png) and replace it. The theme would be automatically changed after next running of the app.

I have tried something like this, but it wants some component like a parameter and the second method wants placeholder (EncodedImage, I am not sure about its purpose) and I don´t know if the image will be automatically replaced in resources.

```
ImageDownloadService.createImageToStorage(URL_IMAGE_ONLINE, button, 
"online-1020x1440.jpg", dimension)

URLImage.createToStorage(EncodedImage placeholder, String storageFile, String url, URLImage.ImageAdapter adapter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing in a theme hash is a bit much when you can just change the image in the `Style` object and avoid a lot of the complexities.

The download services do so in the background and update the target component when they are done, since you don't have a component here this will obviously not work. You can download a file synchronously then load it to the theme using `Util.downloadToStorage`/`FileSystem` but you would need to block until everything completes since you will need a complete image.

You can also download a new resource file or do a myriad of other things if you explain the use case.